# Can compiler optimize virtual function pointer by knowing its offset beforehand

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I use switch/case to get virtual function pointer and call it later.

```
void Application::OnEvent(Event* e)
{
    bool(Layer::* p)(Event*)=nullptr;
    EventType type = e->GetEventType();
    switch (type)
    {
    case Hazel::EventType::MouseMoved:
        p = &Layer::OnMouseMovedEvent;
        break;
    case Hazel::EventType::MouseButtonPressed:
        p = &Layer::OnMouseButtonPressedEvent;
        break;
    case Hazel::EventType::MouseButtonReleased:
        p = &Layer::OnMouseButtonReleasedEvent;
        break;

    }
    LayerStackOnEvent(p, e);
}

void Application::LayerStackOnEvent(bool(Layer::*p)(Event*), Event* e) {
    for (auto iter = m_LayerStack.rbegin(); iter != m_LayerStack.rend(); iter++) {
        if (((*iter)->*p)(e) == true)
            break;
        }
    }
```

Visual Studio Disassembly:

```
lea         rdi,[Hazel::Layer::`vcall'{48}' (07FFD86991890h)] 
lea         rdi,[Hazel::Layer::`vcall'{40}' (07FFD86991898h)] 
lea         rdi,[Hazel::Layer::`vcall'{56}' (07FFD869918A0h)]
…………
Loops start
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbx-8]  // 
add         rbx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8h // rcx=*iter--
call        rdi 
……//Loops end,check if rbx(iter) reach the end.

call rdi go to one of the following
00007FFD86991890  mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FFD86991893  jmp         qword ptr [rax+30h]  
00007FFD86991896  int         3  
00007FFD86991897  int         3  
00007FFD86991898  mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FFD8699189B  jmp         qword ptr [rax+28h]  
00007FFD8699189E  int         3  
00007FFD8699189F  int         3  
00007FFD869918A0  mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FFD869918A3  jmp         qword ptr [rax+38h]
```

I wonder if there is some way to optimize it into something like this

```
lea         rdi,[30h] 
lea         rdi,[28h] 
lea         rdi,[38h]
…………loop start
00007FFD63E717D0  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbx-8]  // rcx=*--iter
00007FFD63E717D4  add         rbx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8h // 
00007FFD86991890  mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FFD86991893  jmp         qword ptr [rax+rdi]  
…………loop end
```

The sequence of functions in vftable seems to depend on the sequence they are declared in the Base Class. So if this .cpp includes the Base.h , it should know the offset of a certain virtual function.

Comment: If you are processing UI events why you care about such micro-optimization? Is your user faster then refresh rate of screen? This is classic case of [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: I ran the performance profile and you're right. It takes <0.1% time.  But it's a generic problem